# Finding product title with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble pulling the product name from a website,
Here is the code I am using -

```
title = product.find('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).text
```

Here is the sites source code for this particular item:

```html
<div class="product-name">
<a class="name-link" href="https://www.hibbett.com/nike-dbreak-type-iron-grey-mens-shoe/M1310.html?dwvar_M1310_color=0411&amp;cgid=mens-newarrivals" data-gtmdata="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;M1310&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Nike DBreak-Type \&quot;Iron Grey\&quot; Men's Shoe&quot;,&quot;parentID&quot;:&quot;M1310&quot;,&quot;brand&quot;:&quot;Nike&quot;,&quot;category&quot;:&quot;/Sneakers/Nike&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:100,&quot;dimension3&quot;:&quot;400&quot;,&quot;dimension4&quot;:&quot;400&quot;,&quot;dimension7&quot;:&quot;Non drop-ship&quot;,&quot;list&quot;:&quot;mens-newarrivals&quot;,&quot;dimension12&quot;:&quot;Not Available&quot;}">
Nike DBreak-Type &quot;Iron Grey&quot; Men&#39;s Shoe
</a>
</div>
```

EDIT:

```
 page = soup(r, 'html.parser')
        products = page.find_all('li', {'class': 'grid-tile'})
        for product in products:
            url = product.find('a')['href']
            url = base_uri + url
            a = collection.find({})
            title = product.find('a', {'class': 'name-link'}).text
```

Returns :

```
title = product.find('a', {'class': 'name-link'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please don't supply information as a screenshot if it is textual information that could be included directly in the question as formatted text, especially code like this.

Comment: Updated for you.

Comment: At least one of the `<li class='grid-title'>` elements does not have an `<a class='name-link'>`. Also i'd recommend writing your bs4 code like this `product.find('a', class_='name-link').get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

There is also an inner a tag:

```
title = product.find('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).a.text
```

Comment: Thanks I tried and got this error :/ ```title = product.find('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).a.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'```

Comment: Try with also `findall` instead.

Comment: Like this? ```title = product.findall('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).a.text```

Comment: Yes try that too

Comment: ```title = product.findall('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).a.text
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable``` I updated the code above so you can see more of it I am not sure if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

The text you want seems to be part of the <a> record, not the outer <div>.  I'm not sure what your `product` object is, because you don't show us that.  This line might work in place of the one you show:

```
title = product.find('a', {'class': 'name-link'}).text
```

Result:

```
Nike DBreak-Type "Iron Grey" Men's Shoe
```

Aha...I only saw @WasifHasan's answer after posting mine.  That works too :). Take your pick.

Comment: I tried this and got the error ```title = soup.find('a', {'class': 'name-link'}).text
  File "C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1756, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'```

Comment: Hmmm...I actually ran code to test it. - I bet mine is wrong then given what your `product` object is.  Go with Wasif's answer if that works for you, which I expect it will.  I'm not a BS expert.

Comment: Oh darn...I didn't change 'soup' to 'product', even though you had 'product'.  Actually, YES!, try that. It might work to change `soup` to `product`!

Comment: Okay this time it managed to find the products but not the title. I will update the code so you can see maybe I did something else wrong.

Comment: Updated for you